# I know what a linear functional is, is there such a thing in mathematics as a nonlinear functional

Tags: linear-algebra

A linear functional is a function from a vector space to its underlying field, which is linear.  Is there such a thing in mathematics as a NONlinear functional?

Comment: A nonlinear function is a non-linear function.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe  Is there not such a thing as non-circular reasoning?

Comment: Take any non-zero constant function.

Comment: A nonlinear functional: $$S(q)=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}L(q,\dot{q},t)dt$$

Comment: @mjw I don't think that nonlinear can mean something else than "which is not linear".

Comment: @mjw Yes, see TheSilverDoe's first comment for an example.

Comment: Okay.  Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a field of non-linear functional analysis. As you can imagine, the class of non-linear functionals is quite diverse and so there isn't a general theory in the same way as their is for linear functionals. But they are still studied.

For an interesting example consider $L:\mathcal{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $\mathcal{R}\subset C([0,1],\mathbb{R}^3)$ is the subspace of rectifiable curves and $L$ is the arclength function.

Answer (score 0):

The term functional can have different meanings in different mathematical contexts. Historically, especially in the context of physics, a functional is simply a "function of functions." Obviously, this can be nonlinear; indeed, a physical system's action (time integral of the Lagrangian) almost always is.

I suspect your question is about the linear algebra conception of linear functionals. Here, a linear functional is a linear map from a vector space to it's field of scalars.

Nonlinear maps are definitely possible; though the powerful theorems of linear algebra would no longer apply.

For example, consider a map $\mathbf{N}:\mathbf{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ which takes every nonzero vector to $0$ and the $0$-vector to $1$. This can easily be shown to be nonlinear.

Comment: Mithrandir Thanks -- that's what I had in mind in the question